# How does Google render it's results on the Search engine results page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome-devtools, google-search

I've first noticed that the results are not in the HTML received from the server therefore I opened Dev Tools and started looking at the other files that my browser downloaded.

I've noticed that there was only one `xhr` request named `gcosuc` and no `json`( nor `xml` or other data files downloaded) therefore I thought the code was embedded in the JS itself.

I then searched all the .js files downloaded by chrome and still I could not find where the search results came from.

The I thought that the search results might be inside and iframe element and because of this they are not shown in Dev Tools. With this hypothesis in mind I looked at the HTML generated by the JS after the DOM was loaded thinking that the result might be embedded in an `iframe` and again I was wrong.

Does anyone have any idea how Google gets and renders it's search results?

Comment: Sounds a bit off-topic

Answer (score 1):

As well as I've been able to figure out, it is all done using JavaScript and rendered dynamically as you scroll.

Google+ works similarly.  Only what you see on the screen is actually on the DOM and it all disappears as you scroll.

If you are trying to screen scrape the results, I would recommend rendering into a browser and looking at the resulting DOM.  I use Chromium.

Comment: "and it all disappears as you scroll." What do you mean by that?

Comment: When you scroll, the DOM elements go away and/or get reused by stuff you can see.

Comment: You mean that when I scroll down the page the top results should disappear from the DOM. How can I see this happening? I've tried using Dev Tools and it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: Also I still don't understand where the data( ie, links and descriptions) comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Made a quick try, and it's indeed an AJAX request. The URI is `/s` and it passes GET parameters, including what you've search.

The response is some kind of awkward JSON that includes text, styles, and some JS. It's like JSON objects, but separated by this chars: `/*""*/`

Here's an example (word wrapped because lines are really long):

[image: Example response]

**Edit** I add the DevTools requests made by Google:

[image: XHR Requests]

Comment: exactly.  Good luck interpreting that.

Comment: Well.. It's not just Google Search that can't be easily interpreted. Any minified/obfuscated is really hard to read. In addition that this will probably work with some closures that you may never find. If you escape every `\u003C` and so on every `d` property, you get HTML, CSS and JS. The JS is not human readable, but it's there.

Comment: @JoaquínO In Dev Tools to only xhr request I see executed is the one with the URI `/gcosuc` that received a lot less JSON than you show in your screenshot. In my case the only JSON I see is `)]}'
[0,"0",0,600,false,"gn"]` .

Comment: @user3790827 as you can see in the screenshot I've added to my answer, there are a lot of xhr requests. The ones that call `/search` are for the search autocomplete. The `/s` requests are the one you're looking for. Double check that you're not filtering the requests at all. They are there, believe me :P